# Next-auth error occurs when trying to get provider

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

This error occurs when I'm trying to get provider data in the login component:

TypeError: (0 , next_auth_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.providers) is not a function

This is my code with simple test to get the provider data

```
import React from "react";
import { providers, getSession } from "next-auth/react";

const Login = ({ providers, session}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {providers.google.name}
    </div>
  );
};

// set provider
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      providers: await providers(context),
      session: await getSession(context),
    },
  };
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: could you share a screenshot of the error and on what line?

Comment: Try using `getProviders` instead. See https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getproviders.

Answer (score 0):

this is because providers is not something you can import from next-auth/react
you might want to use

```
 SessionProvider
```

but since im not 100% what you have to use here. read these docs
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example